# Plot (x, y, z) triples on 2d plane with a colormap

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I'm using `python2` and `matplotlib`.

I have lots of triples `(x, y, z)`. I need to plot them as a kind of **histogram/heatmap** on a 2d plane with the axes `x` and `y` and a color indicating `z`.

The main problem is that x and y are not on any kind of grid but vary freely, so some kind of interpolation is needed.

I tried `contour(X, Y, Z)`, but this takes Z as a 2d array, which means it needs the values on a grid.

Comment: I'd look into `griddata` in `scipy.interpolate` to interpolate your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `hexbin` might be nice if you have tons of (x, y, z) triples with x and y being **well-distributed**, it comes with a lot of rather unpleasant whitespace, if they're not (and/or too few).

Suppose you have

```
X = [ ... ]
Y = [ ... ]
Z = [ ... ]
```

you first need to create a grid

```
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:max(Y):800j, 0:max(X):800j]
```

where `0:max(Y)` is the interval and `800` a step count. Then manually interpolate with

```
values = interpolate.griddata((Y, X), Z, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')
```

which results in a 2d array that can be plotted like this

```
pl.imshow(values, origin='lower', extent=[0, max(X), 0, max(Y)],
          aspect='auto', cmap=pl.get_cmap('YlOrRd'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I like using `hexbin` with it's `C` input option for this sort of thing. For example, if you've parsed your data from tuple-triples into `x_arr`, `y_arr` and `z_arr` arrays, you could do:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import hexbin

hexbin(x_arr, y_arr, C=z_arr)
```

This implicitly averages the data over the hexagonal bins. You can change the `reduce_C_function` option if you want something different than a simple average. You can change the number of bins with the  `gridsize` option.